# How correctly to free the memory after deleting the TList<> items?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

Use `TList` as records container. During application, `TList` adding and deliting big quantity of records. But after `delete`, property `capacity`  never decreases and memory is not freed. How solve that problem?
Simplistic code example:

```
type
  TMyRecord = record
    Num : integer;
    Str : String
  end;

var
  MyRecord : TMyRecord;
  MyList :TList<TMyRecord>;



  MyList := TList<TMyRecord>.Create;

  MyRecord.Num := 1;
  MyRecord.Str := 'abc';

  for i := 0 to 63 do
    begin
      MyList.Add(MyRecord);
    end;

  Memo1.Lines.Add('Before deleting');
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Count='+IntToStr(MyList.Count));
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Capacity='+IntToStr(MyList.Capacity));

  for i := 0 to 59 do
    begin
      MyList.Delete(0);
    end;

  MyList.Pack; // Here need to somehow free the memory.

  Memo1.Lines.Add('After deleting');
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Count='+IntToStr(MyList.Count));
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Capacity='+IntToStr(MyList.Capacity));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation on `TList.Pack`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList.Pack):

> This procedure removes from the list any item of class T with a value that is the default value of T.

The code you posted indicates that you seem to think this reduces the lists `Capacity`, but that's not what this is for.

What you should be using instead is `TList.TrimExcess`. [From the docu](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList.TrimExcess):

> TrimExcess sets Capacity to Count, getting rid of all excess capacity in the list.

Comment: This is exactly that is necessary in my case. Thank you!

Comment: Note: Lazarus has a better help page for 'Capacity'. The one from Delphi is really confusing: https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/classes/tlist.capacity.html

Answer (score 2):

You can write

```
MyList.Capacity := MyList.Count;
```